# "merging" a picture and text into one entity

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to "combine" the image and the text, in such a way that they can be manipulated as 1 entity. So I should be able to, for instance, click the entity (image or text) as a whole, and cut/paste it elsewhere in the textbox, or delete it with a single key press (backspace or DEL key), etc. I am not sure what features HTML supports, but is there a feature that is equivalent to a container/wrapper that "merges" the picture and text into one? (kinda like a "textbox" in MS Word)

I posted my code online, feel free to take a look. http://need-help-with-text-editor.atspace.co.uk/

Comment: Something like this may cover part of your requirements? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I already have the dojo toolkit implemented in my webapp, so using jQuery would be a little difficult..

Comment: I must be missing the point here, but why can't you wrap them both in a div and apply your actions to that?

Comment: @mickylaaaad: I will try that now.. Would I simply just place the following div tags around my image/text code?   <div id="letterA">myCode</div>

Update: Unfortunately the div tag didn't combine them together. Pressing the delete key, for example, still required that each item (pic, text) to be erased individually, rather than together as a whole (like a textbox, for example)

Comment: Put each img and span 'pair' inside a separate div, and apply your logic (e.g. your delete) to that div rather than both the image and the span. This is basic html so I'm not sure if you are lacking fundamental understanding or I have completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: @mickylaaaad: I won't say I'm a web development guru, but I'm fairly familiar with the basics. I tried putting each img and span 'pair' inside a separate div, but how would I apply my logic (delete) to that specific div, while in the text editor, rather than individually to the image and the text, or by highlighting both of them manually?

Answer (score 1):

`figure` tag handles such things. It provides a container for diagrams, photos, etc. with the caption (text).

```
<figure>
    <img src="my_image.png" alt="My Image">
    <figcaption>This is my first image</figcaption>
</figure>
```